# How shall I use Chrome Remote Desktop correctly and access the current remote desktop?

Tags: lubuntu, google-chrome, remote-desktop

I use [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://remotedesktop.google.com/) to access a computer from another. Both are running Lubuntu 18.04 and latest Google Chrome browsers.

In one computer, I added the other computer in Chrome Remote Desktop addon in Google Chrome, so I can access the  remote desktop of the other computer by selecting it. Then what I get is an "empty" desktop different from the current desktop on the other computer, with some error messages (see below).

- Why do I get the error messages?
- How can I access the current desktop on the other computer?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do you insist on using Google Remote Desktop, or are you open to other solutions?

Comment: I do not insist on it. I like to know other options. I also like to know how to use it, in case I miss anything to use its feature.

Comment: On my Lubuntu machines I use vino-server on the remote machine and remmina on the client.  These are more or less the standard Lubuntu tools for this purpose.

Comment: Setup instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers

Comment: Can you use Vino across the internet? I think that is where Chrome Remote Desktop excels?

Comment: Sure. The proper ports have to be open in your router. You can tunnel it over ssh, that's what I do for better security.

Comment: Do you restrict direct accessibility to Vino to the Vino server host and then use ssh port forwarding to access Vino?

Comment: Not exactly because I allow computers on our LAN to connect to vino-server using the native port 5900.  But outside connections must come on ssh over a port I have open anyway. remmina (the client) has ssh tunnel capability built in.

Comment: Thanks. Could you try Chrome Remote Desktop, and see if you have the same questions as I? Do you like it as much as your current solution?

Comment: I try to avoid Google stuff as much as possible.

Comment: Could you   experiment just for this post?

Answer (score 0):

Run into the same issue. Solved it this way:

Make sure to have an **.chrome-remote-desktop-session** file in the useres home folder with the LXDE config: *exec /usr/bin/lxsession -s Lubuntu -e LXDE*

You can just run the following command:

```
echo "exec /usr/bin/lxsession -s Lubuntu -e LXDE" > ~/.chrome-remote-desktop-session
```